# ImageView disappear in Sliding up panel

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a problem. I have ViewPager with 3 Fragments(Pages). In first fragment I have sliding up panel. I used for it this library from GitHub. Click [here](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). In TitleBar of that sliding panel I have ImageView as in the picture below. ImageView changes when user open or close Sliding up panel.

[image]

**MY PROBLEM:** When I change the Fragment (move to another page) and go back to first page ImageVIew disappear. Whats the reason?!

**Fragment1.java**: (setPanelSlideListener is in the onViewCreated method which is called immediately when the view is created...)

```
mSlidingUpPanelLayout.setPanelSlideListener(new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelSlide, offset " + slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelCollapsed(View panel) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelCollapsed");
                mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_up);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelExpanded(View panel) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelExpanded");
                mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_down);
                fab.setColorPressed(getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_up_pressed));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelAnchored(View panel) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelAnchored");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelHidden(View panel) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelHidden");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelHiddenExecuted(View panel, Interpolator interpolator, int duration) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelHiddenExecuted");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelShownExecuted(View panel, Interpolator interpolator, int duration) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelShownExecuted");
                mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_up);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelExpandedStateY(View panel, boolean reached) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelExpandedStateY" + (reached ? "reached" : "left"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelCollapsedStateY(View panel, boolean reached) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPanelCollapsedStateY" + (reached ? "reached" : "left"));
                if (reached) {
          fab.setColorPressed(getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_pressed));
                    mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                }else{
                                        fab.setColorPressed(getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_up_pressed));
                    mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelLayout(View panel, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState state) {
                if(state == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED){
                    titleBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#03A9F4"));
                    fab.setColorNormal(getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_primary));
                    fab.setColorPressed(getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_pressed));
                    mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_up);
                }
                else if (state == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED || state == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED){
                    titleBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff9431"));
                    fab.setColorNormal(getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_up_primary));
                    fab.setColorPressed(getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_up_pressed));
                    mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_down);
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks for any help! Need any help!

Answer (score 1):

I have used umano library in my many apps. Have you try saving its state?

Please add below code, which saved your state while you coming back from the another fragment.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     outState.putBoolean(SAVED_STATE_ACTION_BAR_HIDDEN,
     mLayout.isExpanded());
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
public static final String SAVED_STATE_ACTION_BAR_HIDDEN = "saved_state_action_bar_hidden";
```

Instead of `isExpanded()`, it might be `isPanelExpanded()` or `isPaneExpanded()` as per the library you have used.

Please update it with respect to that methods and let me know.

Let me know if it not resolved your issue.

I will like to help you out.
Enjoy Coding... :)

Comment: Hello @nDroidDev How are you? I really need help! I added your code and I have some mistakes such as "cannot resolve method" in SAVED_STATE_ACTION_BAR_HIDDEN and the same mistake in isExpanded()... What I need to add too?

Answer (score 0):

Use `addPanelSlideListener` in place of `setPanelSlideListener`